# Update jQuery variable on ajax complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im still a beginner with JS.

I use ajax for filtering content in wordpress. So I need to send 2 variables to PHP. But the problem is once i've navigated further one of the variables needs to change. In html the Data gets changed, but jquery which runs on (document).ready uses the initial variable. How can i make the variable refresh on ajax complete?

here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.tax-filter').click( function(event) {

    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }

    var selecetd_taxonomy = $(this).attr('id');
    var personData = $('#content').data('id');


    data = {
        action: 'filter_posts',
        afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
        taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy,
        person: personData,
    };


    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
        data: data,
        success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {
            $('.showContent').html( data.response );
        },

        error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            $('.projects').html( 'Error 404' );
        }
    })
});
});
```

From another function the .data('id') in html gets a new value, but I need the jQuery to get the new value aswell

EDIT:

I need the personData to be updated in my click function. 
The data-id value of #content gets updated on ajaxComplete. It is done by another click function which gets the value from PHP.

Comment: `if (event.preventDefault) {` why are you doing that check in jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [update javascript variable with ajax in real-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978449/update-javascript-variable-with-ajax-in-real-time)

Comment: *"From another function the .data('id') in html gets a new value, but I need the jQuery to get the new value as well"* Get the value where? Where is it setting the new id?

Comment: you did not mention what variable you want to change

Comment: The $('#content').data('id'); gets a new value on ajaxComplete. I need the var personData to be updated in the function I posted above.

Comment: You want to change the value of personeData?

Comment: Yes, the data-id of #content gets a new value on a click from another menu. But the function above uses the first one it gets when the page is loaded. Because the document.ready right? but how could I update personData in this function on ajaxComplete?

Comment: Can we see the other function that sets the new data-id?

Comment: $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
 var personID = $('#id').data('id');
 $('#content').attr('data-id', personID);
});

The data-id gets updated when another page is loaded. The function i Posted above is not for pages but for filtering with tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the data-id using `$('#content').data('id', 'newValueHere')` instead of `$('#content').attr('data-id', 'newValue')`

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1nyr21c/) and note that changing the attribute with .attr() doesn't work, but .data() does.

Comment: this and correcting a few typos fixed my problem!

Thanks